# Wordpress: remove Prev/Next link from post

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Im trying to remove the Next / Prev link and the header at the top of the page but its not working. I have try many things and nothing is working so far. I'm using the Comic Press theme.....Any idea?

https://ghostclasses.com/koan/

Comment: For all the post that is, i need to remove those from the website in general

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-previous-and-next-post-links-at-bottom-of-posts/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove using CSS:

```
.blognav {
    display: none;
}
```

If this above CSS is not working then try the below CSS code:

```
.blognav {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: .blognav {display: none !important} you can add css in custom setting

Answer (score 0):

Well all you have to do is go to your wordpress dashboard and view the header settings and try checking the navigation of it so you can be able to remove it or you could remove it directly from the source code of the website on wordpress.Hope that works

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Comic Press theme but if anything is not working then use CSS.

```
.blognav {
   display:none;
}
```

This will remove the top navigation.

Hope this will solve your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove permanently then you should find class='blognav' in your Wordpress theme directory and comment this div. So you can uncomment again if future needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful to anyone without the Comic Press theme. I have the TwentySix theme, and the only answers I had found involved modifying the CSS. None of these worked to remove the previous-next links at the bottom of each post.

The solution I found was to open the `single.php` file and comment out the PHP if and elseif statements that call the `the_post_navigation` function like so:

```
            /*
            if ( is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) {
                // Parent post navigation.
                the_post_navigation(
                    array(
                        'prev_text' => _x( '<span class="meta-nav">Published in</span><span class="post-title">%title</span>', 'Parent post link', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    )
                );
            } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                the_post_navigation(
                    array(
                        'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                    )
                );
            }
            */
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment these lines in the single.php file :

```
<!-- <div class="row mb-5 prevnextlinks justify-content-center align-items-center"> 
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 rightborder pl-0"><div class="thepostlink"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-right pr-0"><div class="thepostlink"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div></div>
</div>  -->
```